# How to obtain roles from ASP.NET Identity ApplicationGroupRoles table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I can retrieve all the roles for a user from **AspNetUserRoles** table in the prior version of ASP.NET Identity as shown below:

```
ApplicationUser user = UserManager.FindByName(model.UserName);
string userId = user != null ? user.Id : null;
var roles = userId != null ? UserManager.GetRoles(userId) : null;
if (roles != null)
{
    foreach (var item in roles)
    {
        //Assign user roles
        UserManager.AddToRole(userId, item);
    }
}
```

However, as the roles are assigned to the users via **ApplicationGroupRoles** and **ApplicationUserGroups** tables, this UserManager.GetRoles(userId) method does not works as it only retrieves roles from **AspNetUserRoles** table. So, how to manage to retrieve roles for a given user i.e. looking at **ApplicationUserGroups** first then **ApplicationGroupRoles** table? **Or is the only way to retrieve them by using sql command**? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: although i have posted another way to find the roles but your code is working fine did you enter any roles in table AspNetRoles and created the relation between user and roles in table AspNetUserRoles

Comment: @rashfmnb Yes, I can receive from AspNetUserRoles table, but I need to obtain ApplicationGroupRoles table values.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I use the following statements in order to obtain related values:

```
ApplicationGroupManager gm = new ApplicationGroupManager();
string roleName = RoleManager.FindById("").Name; //Returns Role Name by using Role Id 
var userGroupRoles = gm.GetUserGroupRoles(""); //Returns Group Id and Role Id by User Id var 
groupRoles = gm.GetGroupRoles(""); //Returns Group Roles by using Group Id
string[] groupRoleNames = groupRoles.Select(p => p.Name).ToArray(); //Assing Group Role Names to a string array
```

```
//Returns Group Id and Role Id by using User Id parameter
var userGroupRoles = groupManager.GetUserGroupRoles(""); 
foreach (var role in userGroupRoles)
{
    string roleName = RoleManager.FindById(role.ApplicationRoleId).Name;
    UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, roleName);
}
```

```
//Sets the uıser's group id
var defaultGroup = "";
groupManager.SetUserGroups(newUser.Id, new string[] { defaultGroup });
```

By using them, now I can easily retrieve the necessary values I need. Thanks a lot @rashfmnb.

Answer (score 1):

although i have posted another way to find the roles but your code us fine did you enter any roles in table

> AspNetRoles

and created the relation between user and roles in table

> AspNetUserRoles

To find all the role for specific user you can use the following code

```
    RoleBasedSecurity.Models.ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    ApplicationUser au = context.Users.First(u => u.UserName == "admin@admin.com");

    foreach (IdentityUserRole role in au.Roles)
    {
        string name = role.RoleId;
        string RoleName = context.Roles.First(r => r.Id == role.RoleId).Name;
    }
```

Code for Creating Roles Write these lines in **protected override void Seed(RoleBasedSecurity.Models.ApplicationDbContext context)** in **cofiguration.cs**

```
    if (!context.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == "User"))
    {
        var store = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);
        var manager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(store);
        var role = new IdentityRole { Name = "User" };

        manager.Create(role);
    }
```

Code for attaching users to role Write these lines in **protected override void Seed(RoleBasedSecurity.Models.ApplicationDbContext context)** in **cofiguration.cs**

```
    if (!context.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == "admin@admin.com"))
    {
        var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
        var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store);
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "admin@admin.com", Email = "admin@admin.com" };
        manager.Create(user, "password");
        manager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Admin");
    }
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. Just found time to try to test your answer and for the first part, and obtained that: au.Roles is filled with AspNetUserRoles table instead of ApplicationGroupRoles. So, as I mentioned above, how can I retrieve the roles from ApplicationGroupRoles table? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. As far as I see there are some useful built in method in ASP.NET Identity 2 for this. Your answer is also useful and I appreciated it. Thanks and vote+